# How to get position info of each node in CATIA using C#

Tags: c#, catia

I'm using CATIA V5R27 for work. The manual operation for automation is firstly, I switch to "`DMU Navigator`" workbench. Then I activate a node and click "`Translation or Rotation`" button. After that I choose "`Position`" tab and check the data.

[image: Translation orRotation button]

[image: Data need to get]

Could someone tell me how to do that or which library should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the *Instance Product* object that you are interested in then you can get it's transformation matrix from the Product's Position property. So something like:

```
// get CATIA object
var oCATIA = (INFITF.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application");

// Get active document
var oDoc = oCATIA.ActiveDocument;

// get the instance product of the selected object
var oInstProd = (Product)oDoc.Selection.Item(1).LeafProduct;

// declare a safe array for the transformation matrix
Array tx = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), 12);

// get the transformation matrix components
oInstProd.Position.GetComponents(tx);

//print the results
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(((object[])tx)[0].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[1].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[2].ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(((object[])tx)[3].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[4].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[5].ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(((object[])tx)[6].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[7].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[8].ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(((object[])tx)[9].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[10].ToString() + ", " + ((object[])tx)[11].ToString());
```

This is the transformation matrix of that specific node. If the node is a child of other products, you must multiply this matrix with the matricies of it's parents to get the absolute transformation.

You will need the type libaries INFITF and ProductStructureTypeLib as references.